# How to replace text with comma [Linux on Windows]

Tags: regex, linux, sed, windows-subsystem-for-linux

We get these automated emails from our client that have this rough format:

```
VP##0-X1-#####-#[Revision #:Document title]
VP##0-X2-#####-#[Revision #:Document title]
VP##0-X3-#####-#[Revision #:Document title]
```

What I want to do:

- replace `[Revision` with a comma
- replace `:` with a comma
- delete `]`

So that I can convert this into a CSV and then use some excel magic to fill in our tracking sheet.

I've tried to use `sed` with this general format:

`sed -i 's,[Revision ,\,,g' <FILE>`

but I don't know how to get a comma in for this case.

This is what I want to get in the end:

```
VP##0-X1-#####-#,#,Document title
VP##0-X2-#####-#,#,Document title
VP##0-X3-#####-#,#,ocument title
```

Any and all insight is appreciated.

I'm using Ubuntu on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -Ei 's/(.*)(\[Revision)(.*)(:)(.*)(])/\1,\3,\5/' <FILE>
```

Testing it with one line and an echo:

```
$ echo "[VP##0-X1-#####-#[Revision #:Document title]" | sed -E 's/(.*)(\[Revision)(.*)(:)(.*)(])/\1,\3,\5/'
[VP##0-X1-#####-#, #,Document title
```

**Explanation:**

- `'(.*)(\[Revision)(.*)(:)(.*)(])`

The regular expression in the first half of the `sed` command is divided into 6 groups defined by `()`.
Group 2 `(\[Revision)` will match `"[Revision"` and group 4 `(:)` will match `":"`, the parts of the string you want to replace.

- `/\1,\3,\5/'`

In the second part of the command, the same groups can be used as the replacement text, so I used group 1 (`\1`) to preserve everything before `"[Revision"`, then use a comma `','`, then use group 3 (`\3`) (everything between `"[Revision"` and `":"`), a comma `","`, and finally group 5 (`\5`). Group 6 will match the final `']'`, so it is not used as you wanted to remove it.

Comment: This worked perfectly! is there a chance you can comment on what each component does so I can try to understand it better?

Comment: It's Done @JesseTherrien

Comment: thank you so much, i've been able to modify the code a bit more to solve another problem!

Answer (score 3):

```
sed  's/\[Revision /,/;s/:/,/;s/]//' inputfile
VP##0-X1-#####-#, #,Document title
VP##0-X2-#####-#, #,Document title
VP##0-X3-#####-#, #,Document title
```

No need to use heavy lifting by using `back-referencing` or using multiple `sed` commands. You can issue multiple replacement commands from within single `sed` command:

Syntax:

```
sed 's/a/A/' file
sed 's/b/B/' file
sed 's/c/C/' file
```

Can be combined into one command:

```
sed 's/a/A/;s/b/B/;s/c/C/' file   #note the semicolon separating multiple replace operations.
```

Comment: You miss a space, should be `sed  's/\[Revision /,/;s/:/,/;s/]//'`

Answer (score 0):

The `[` must be escaped since it is a special character for regular expressions. Also, it may be better to use another character than `,` as separator in the `sed` command. This should do the trick:

```
sed -i 's/\[Revision /,/g' <FILE>
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed, `/` is a pretty common separator.  Also, square brackets are special characters and need to be escaped.

**replace `[Revision` with a comma**

```
sed -i 's/\[Revision /,/g' <FILE>
```

**replace `:` with a comma**

```
sed -i 's/:/,/g' <FILE>
```

**delete `]`**

```
sed -i 's/\]//g' <FILE>
```